# Java blurrying background with Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics2d

I'm using Java to create an image with text. I set the color of the background and fill it up. Then I place the text using LineBreakMeasurer. The problem is (As you can see in the attached image) the image background around the text is blurry (if you zoom on). This is a problem for me. Is it possible to fix that?

```
final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(600, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g2d = image.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setColor(new Color(255,0,0));
    g2d.fillRect (0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
```

...

```
AttributedString attributedString = getAttributedString(text, fontSize, new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0.9f));
    AttributedCharacterIterator characterIterator = attributedString
            .getIterator();
    FontRenderContext fontRenderContext = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
    LineBreakMeasurer measurer = new LineBreakMeasurer(characterIterator,
            fontRenderContext);
    while (measurer.getPosition() < characterIterator.getEndIndex()) {
        TextLayout textLayout = measurer.nextLayout(width);
        int currentX = x + (int)(width - textLayout.getVisibleAdvance()) / 2;
        y += textLayout.getAscent();

        textLayout.draw(g2d, currentX, y);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: If you're referring to the artifacts around the letters, the problem isn't with your painting code.  It's the result of saving the image as a JPEG.  Save it using a non-lossy format, like PNG.  You could also try reducing the compression of the JPEG, but saving as a PNG is probably easier.

Comment: That's exactly right. Thank you very much. If you want you can answer with that answer and I'll mark it as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to the artifacts around the letters, the problem isn't with your painting code. It's the result of saving the image as a JPEG. Save it using a non-lossy format, like PNG. You could also try reducing the compression of the JPEG, but saving as a PNG is probably easier.